# How to Refresh GridView in C#.Net Windows Form?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to Refresh GridView after data inserted.
In ASP.Net GridView1.DataBind().That's work.
But I don't know how to do that in C#.Net Windows Form.
Please answer me if you know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this works

```
GridView1.Invalidate();
```

Check this [Control.Invalidate Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a.aspx)

Comment: I don't think this will work. Invalidate() only schedules the grid to be re-drawn; not repopulated.

Comment: @Soge: don't forget to mark this question as correct if your problem was solved

Comment: @soge, does the suggestion worked for you? I see you commented saying it didn't worked for you but I see that it's marked as answer. M confused :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you bind your grid to, but you could always repeat the binding by re-setting the DataSource property

Comment: I'm showing gridview in form_Load Event..And after insert data into Microsoft Access Database , then gridview don't show that data i did.

Comment: You need to refetch the data from the database again

Comment: What is refetch?..is it Refresh?if refresh how can i do that?

Comment: how did you put data into the grid in the first place, do the same

Comment: I'm developing Dictionary Program.After insert new words into aceess database . First time and second time are only show that word i inserted.third time it not show.That's another problem...I don't know how to do that ..